# How do I groupby and aggregate column in Spark and create nested Json

Tags: apache-spark, group-by, apache-spark-sql, aggregation

> I have data like this and I want to create following JSON Document.
>   How can I achieve it in Spark? What is the most efficient way to do it in Spark?

```
 name|contact           |type
    jack|123-123-1234       |phone
    jack|jack.reach@xyz.com |email
    jack|123 main street    |address
    jack|34545544445        |mobile

       {
         "name" : "jack",
         "contacts":[
         {
           "contact" : "123-123-1234",
           "type" : "phone"
         },
         {
           "contact" : "jack.reach@xyz.com",
           "type" : "email"
         },
        {
           "contact" : "123 main street",
            "type" : "address"
        },
        {
           "contact" : "34545544445",
           "type" : "mobile"
        }
      ]
    }
```

> This is just a sample use case I provided. I have large data set where
>   I have to collapse multi column rows into one row with some grouping
>   logic.
>
> My Current approach is I write a UDAF that reads each row, stores in
>   buffer and merge it. So the code would be

```
val mergeUDAF = new ColumnUDAF

val tempTable = inputTable.withColumn("contacts",struct($"contact",$"type")
val outputTable = tempTable.groupby($"name").agg(mergeUDAF($"contacts").alias("contacts"))
```

> I am trying to figure out what other approaches there can be. I am
>   trying to achieve this using Spark-SQL.

Comment: Please, add more information for the question. Show what you try.

Comment: @Thiago Baldim Sorry, Updated the question with more detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case class contact(contact:String,contactType:String)
case class Person(name:String,contact:Seq[contact])
    object SparkTestGrouping {

      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("LocalTest").setMaster("local")
        val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
        val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
        import sqlContext.implicits._


        val inputData=Seq("jack|123-123-1234|phone","jack|jack.reach@xyz.com|email","jack|123 main street|address","jack|34545544445|mobile")


        val finalData = sc.parallelize(inputData)

        val convertData = finalData.map(_.split('|'))
          .map(line => (line(0),Seq(line(1) +"|" +line(2))))
          .reduceByKey((x,y) => x ++: y)

          val output = convertData.map(line => (line._1,line._2.map(_.split('|')).map(obj => contact(obj(0),obj(1)))))

        val finalOutput = output.map(line => Person(line._1,line._2))

        finalOutput.toDF().toJSON.foreach(println)

        sc.stop()

      }

    }
```

> You can crate tuples from the data with the key field and use
>   reducebyKey to group the data. In the above example, I created a tuple
>   (name,Seq("contact|contactType")) and used reducebykey to group the
>   data by name. After the data is grouped, you can use case class to
>   convert to DataFrame and DataSets if you need to do further join on it
>   or simply have to create json document.

Comment: While the code you posted clearly works for OP, please post some narrative explaining it to help future visitors to the site understand what you did.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just create an RDD form your csv data, group by "name" than map to json string:

```
 val data = sc.parallelize(Seq("jack|123-123-1234|phone", "jack|jack.reach@xyz.com |email", "david|123 main street|address", "david|34545544445|mobile")) // change to load your data as RDD

 val result = data.map(_.split('|')).groupBy(a => a(0)).map(a => {
    val contact = a._2.map(c => s"""{"contact": "${c(1)}", "type": "${c(2)}" }""" ).mkString(",")
    s"""{"name": "${a._1}", "contacts":[ ${contact}] }"""
  }).collect.mkString(",")

  val json = s"""[ ${result} ] """
```